# Pandas Pivot Table how to add a String Comparison Function column with pulldown rows

Tags: python, pandas, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have created pivot tables using pandas and its pivot table function that I write to excel that represent some computer systems in my company and oodles of meta data. I want to look at that data and highlight where various internal rules have not being followed like naming conventions, versions being out of date etc.

```
# iDistinct_count counts distinct strings 
# iValues lists out unique values
kdPT = pd.pivot_table(df, index="iAID", values=["Application", "Env"], aggfunc=[iDistinct_count, iValues], margins=False)
kdPT.to_excel(reportXLSX, sheet_name="app", startrow=0)
```

In the simplest case I want to make sure all the AppName values are in upper case.

```
AppName | isItUpperCase
apaCHE  | No
DATABASE| Yes
```

I know the how to pivot the data and create new columns for totals and percentages but for a string formula how would I add a string formula something like =exact(a2m upper(a2)) that highlight cells containing lower case

In the end I want my excel to look like this...

```
   A       | B
1: AppName | isItUpperCase
2: apaCHE  | =EXACT(A2,UPPER(A2))  
3: DATABASE| =EXACT(A3,UPPER(A4))
```

I played around with pivot tables and lamdas but based on numerical examples...

```
kdPT.loc\[:, 'Appname all upper'\] = \[f"=EXACT(E{c},UPPER(E{c}))" for c in kdPT.shape\[0\]\]
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of `df`? Also do you want to add an Excel formula? or the text of it? or to compute the result with pandas code?

Comment: I don't have a reproducible df to hand as it comes from an excel sheet with about 80 columns 10000s of rows..   I simplified it above as it is pretty esoteric.     My original intent was to have the python code add an excel formula as a piece of text that when opened in excel would give the appropriate result.  But since you mentioned compute the result with pandas code then yes I think that would be just an answer as well...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `upper`:

```
df["isItUpperCase"] = df["AppName"].eq(df["AppName"].str.upper())

>>> df
    AppName  isItUpperCase
0    apaCHE          False
1  DATABASE           True
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"AppName": ["apaCHE","DATABASE"]})
```

Comment: This solution does it as well... thanks.  I slightly prefer the other one just from a style point of view but this one has a simplicity to it that might make it easy to adapt to my solution.

Comment: Note that the solution I provided is vectorized. `apply` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the 'isItUpperCase' directly in Pandas before exporting to Excel. The result will be a new column in your DataFrame with 'Yes' or 'No' as values like below:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "iAID": [1, 2],
    "AppName": ["apaCHE", "DATABASE"]
})

# Create a new column to indicate if the AppName is in upper case
df['isItUpperCase'] = df['AppName'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x.isupper() else 'No')

# Write to Excel
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name="app", index=False)
```

Comment: This is marvellous.  It works like a treat for my problem and is extensible to my other scenarios such as checking version numbers, naming convention compliance etc.  Importantly it has taught me a couple o things.   First I wanted to apply this to my pivot table and not  the raw data frame but I had to adapt it to my multi index pivot.  Not too tricky but felt that my understanding was improved once I got it.   Also in hindsight I think that applpying the checking logic is  going to to be easier in Python for most of my use-cases except where comparing with data from other sheets.